# How to enumerate all dependency properties of control?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have some WPF control. For example, TextBox. How to enumerate all dependency properties of that control (like XAML editor does)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public IList<DependencyProperty> GetAttachedProperties(DependencyObject obj)
{
    List<DependencyProperty> result = new List<DependencyProperty>();

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj,
        new Attribute[] { new PropertyFilterAttribute(PropertyFilterOptions.All) }))
    {
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd =
            DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(pd);

        if (dpd != null)
        {
            result.Add(dpd.DependencyProperty);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/580234cb-e870-4af1-9a91-3e3ba118c89c

Answer (score 14):

Using reflection is not needed (and a bad idead IMHO) because the framework has already utility classes for this (but they're not obvious to find :-).

Here is an answer based on this article: [Enumerate Bindings](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d47114a7-b182-485c-b1dd-1078ddd42be9/enumerate-bindings?forum=wpf) and the [LocalValueEnumerator Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.localvalueenumerator.aspx)

```
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyProperty> EnumerateDependencyProperties(this DependencyObject obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            LocalValueEnumerator lve = obj.GetLocalValueEnumerator();
            while (lve.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return lve.Current.Property;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is another answer based on this other article: [Getting list of all dependency/attached properties of an Object](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/580234cb-e870-4af1-9a91-3e3ba118c89c/getting-list-of-all-dependencyattached-properties-of-an-object?forum=wpf) that uses [MarkupWriter.GetMarkupObjectFor Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms590313.aspx).

```
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyProperty> EnumerateDependencyProperties(object element)
    {
        if (element != null)
        {
            MarkupObject markupObject = MarkupWriter.GetMarkupObjectFor(element);
            if (markupObject != null)
            {
                foreach (MarkupProperty mp in markupObject.Properties)
                {
                    if (mp.DependencyProperty != null)
                        yield return mp.DependencyProperty;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DependencyProperty> EnumerateAttachedProperties(object element)
    {
        if (element != null)
        {
            MarkupObject markupObject = MarkupWriter.GetMarkupObjectFor(element);
            if (markupObject != null)
            {
                foreach (MarkupProperty mp in markupObject.Properties)
                {
                    if (mp.IsAttached)
                        yield return mp.DependencyProperty;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use reflection, via the GetFields, method to find all the public static properties on TextBox. You can then use a Linq Where clause to filter these to any of type DependencyProperty:

```
  var flags = BindingFlags.Static |
              BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy |
              BindingFlags.Public;
  var dependencyProperties = typeof(TextBox).GetFields(flags)
                     .Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(DependencyProperty));
```

You can then transform this to a list of names via a Select:

```
  var dependencyProperties = typeof(TextBox).GetFields(flags)
                     .Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(DependencyProperty))
                     .Select(dp => dp.Name);
```

Note: each name has a 'Property' suffix, you can of course remove this in the above Select clause if you like.

Comment: +1 for `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy`. Mine does not have it.

Comment: This solution isn't good. See this topic at MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d47114a7-b182-485c-b1dd-1078ddd42be9/ . See Dr.WPF's comment.

Comment: Regarding Dr.WPFs comments, (1) Sure, reflection is slow, but it is the only way to do this, if speed is an issue, cache the results. (2) The method above does not rely on the presence of CLR accessors, so this is not an issue, (3) This method will find attached properties also.

Comment: Colin, create a static class, register an dependency property as attached property in that class, and bind to your attached property to any control. Then enumerate control's dependency properties via your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want name of the DependencyProperties of an element then you can do this:

```
    var results = from prop in typeof(element).GetFields() 
                  where prop.FieldType == typeof(DependencyProperty)
                  select prop.Name.Substring(0, prop.Name.Length - 8);
```

where 8 is length of the string "Property" which appears at the end of a dependency property!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
        var fieldInfos = typeof(TextBox).GetFields( BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).Where(x=>x.FieldType == typeof(DependencyProperty));
        foreach (var fieldInfo in fieldInfos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fieldInfo.Name);
        }
```