# Is it possible to query dependency properties registered for a type?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I'd like to dynamically register some dependency properties in the static constructor of a class. Using the type of that class, is it possible to query the dependency property system for a list of registered properties?

**I don't have corresponding CLR properties for each dependency property**, as I'm trying to keep the amount of code to a minimum.

`DependencyPropertyDescriptor.GetChildProperties()` looks like it might be helpful, but it's an instance method, and there's no public constructor for `DependencyPropertyDescriptor`. It looks like this queries the CLR properties on the type anyway which I don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said ...

> I'd like to dynamically register some dependency properties in the
>   static constructor of a class.

I am afraid its not possible.

But if you want to view existing deendency properties in the Dependency Object using reflection then thats possible...

[How to enumerate all dependency properties of control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794071/how-to-enumerate-all-dependency-properties-of-control)

Comment: Thanks for your response. It looks like `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` will only work if there's a CLR property wrapping the dependency property.