# Get all Dependency Properties for a control

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I need to determine if a control on my window has a specific dependency property declared. Here is an example of a button with the DP DemandRole. That DP can be declared for various control types, not only buttons. I'm trying to enumerate all controls on a window and return only those which have the DP DemandRole declared.

```
<Button x:Name="_reset"
        sec:SecurityAction.DemandRole="Admin,Engineer,SuperUser,Technician,Supervisor" 
        Content="_Reset"
        Visibility="Visible"
        Command="{Binding ResetPasswordCommand}" />
```

I've can get Dependency Properties for a specific type, but that only returns properties for the type and does contain the DP I have defined for the controls.

```
static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetDependencyProperties(Type type)
{
        var dependencyProperties = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
                                       .Where(p => p.FieldType.Equals(typeof(DependencyProperty)));
        return dependencyProperties;
    }
```

Any idea how I can get all DPs on a specific instance of a control?

Thanks,

Lance

Comment: So in short you need all the dependency property of the type and its base types? is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this code example from the [Getting list of all dependency/attached properties of an Object](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/580234cb-e870-4af1-9a91-3e3ba118c89c/getting-list-of-all-dependencyattached-properties-of-an-object?forum=wpf) page on the Visual Studio Forum. I can't guarantee that it will work but it 'appears' to have helped the original question author.

```
public static class DependencyObjectHelper
{
    public static List<DependencyProperty> GetDependencyProperties(Object element)
    {
        List<DependencyProperty> properties = new List<DependencyProperty>();
        MarkupObject markupObject = MarkupWriter.GetMarkupObjectFor(element);
        if (markupObject != null)
        {
            foreach (MarkupProperty mp in markupObject.Properties)
            {
                if (mp.DependencyProperty != null)
                {
                    properties.Add(mp.DependencyProperty);
                }
            }
        }

        return properties;
    }

    public static List<DependencyProperty> GetAttachedProperties(Object element)
    {
        List<DependencyProperty> attachedProperties = new List<DependencyProperty>();
        MarkupObject markupObject = MarkupWriter.GetMarkupObjectFor(element);
        if (markupObject != null)
        {
            foreach (MarkupProperty mp in markupObject.Properties)
            {
                if (mp.IsAttached)
                {
                    attachedProperties.Add(mp.DependencyProperty);
                }
            }
        }

        return attachedProperties;
    }
}
```

If these extension methods don't help, there are other examples on the linked page.

---

UPDATE >>>

I just found this question here on Stack Overflow that might also help:

> [How to enumerate all dependency properties of control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794071/how-to-enumerate-all-dependency-properties-of-control)

Comment: Thanks Sheridan, the updated link you added worked great!!

Comment: Glad to help. In that case, I will close this question as a duplicate of the linked one as preferred on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but I guess you need [BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) flag.

```
static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetDependencyProperties(Type type)
{
     var dependencyProperties = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
                                       .Where(p => p.FieldType.Equals(typeof(DependencyProperty)));
     return dependencyProperties;
}
```

If that doesn't work, you need to call `type.BaseType.GetFields` recursively till `BaseType` returns `null` and concat all the fields.

Comment: FlattenHierachy didn't return the DP, recursively going through the base types also didn't return the DP.