# Discovering Attached and Dependency Properties in Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, dependency-properties, silverlight-5.0, attached-properties

What is the best way, not using "brute force", to find out all attached and dependency properties of an object or type?

Comment: Duplicate ? see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794071/how-to-enumerate-all-dependency-properties-of-control

Comment: No, that one is for WPF and won't work in Silverlight. Also, the proposed solution is what I call "brute force".