# VSIX Project - Properties tool window extension

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, visual-studio-shell, common-project-system

There might be something wrong with the way I search for things but here is my problem. I'm looking for a way to implement a custom editing tool within the properties tool window in the Visual Studio editor. I've been looking through several documentation references, and they all lead to the use of different assemblies, but I can't get anything to work the way that I want.

First of all, I tried using the **UITypeEditor** class, with the step-by-step tuto I found here : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor?view=net-5.0
The problem I faced was that it only seemed to be working with Winforms projects, and I'm trying to use this with a WPF project.

Afterwards, I tried following this tutorial, in order to create a *project template* : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-a-basic-project-system-part-1?view=vs-2019
This has led me to think that the methods used in the tutorial might have been either deprecated or improved with the used of **AsyncPackages** instead of **ProjectPackages**, and the appearance of the **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Flavor** assembly that seem to render useless the **ProjectNode** class (it doesn't even show up anymore, the method has been replaced with a void).

The last bit I tried exploring was the use of the **ProjectSystem**, as documented here : https://github.com/microsoft/VSProjectSystem
It was actually worse because I couldn't get it to work like I wanted, the project type I was creating could not register C# files and I wasn't able to add new classes (I might need to dig a bit deeper here but I don't know where to look).

So basically, I'm looking for help to extend the properties tool window, through an editor within the window, or a modal window opened by clicking on an ellipsis button in the properties window.

Thank you for reading this, if you have any info, I'm very interested.

Comment: This is [a guidance about what you want](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-the-properties-task-list-output-and-options-windows?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Thanks ! I've actually been using this link too, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. This doesn't help me extending the properties tool window, it's a whole new window. Actually, what I'd need would be a way to have a button instead of a textbox in the properties window when you click on a property of a specific control in the XAML Designer. And this button would open a tool window where I can modify the property. I need this to implement a custom way to create Bindings in WPF.

Comment: Not sure if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41491276/get-wpf-control-properties-from-the-properties-window/41695285) helps.

Comment: Well it wasn't the thing I was looking for but it still valuable information that I'll use, thank you! I've solved my problem

Comment: Be glad to know that you have solved your issue by yourself. To improve this ticket, you could add an answer about your workaround here and then [mark your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/):) It is kind of you to do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually found a thread leading to what I was trying to do [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb546930(v=vs.110)). This tutorial leads to a way to implement a customized editor, either inline, extended or in another dialog window. This was the thing I needed, and with a few tweaks I managed doing what I wanted.

Comment: Since you have a workaround, I suggest you could [mark your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/?_ga=2.180598695.1251105754.1615773183-584939326.1612145624)